# VirtualBox sound problem under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, virtualbox, audio

As I recently upgraded to karmic I started to see the following stuff in the logs when I run VirtualBox:

```
Oct 30 18:14:34 apocalypse pulseaudio[2813]: alsa-source.c: Resume failed, couldn't restore original fragment settings. (Old: 65536/65536, New 1073676288/65532)io[2813]: alsa-source.c: Resume failed, couldn't restore original fragment settings. (Old: 65536/65536, New 1073676288/65532)io[2813]: alsa-source.c: Resume failed, couldn't restore original fragment settings. (Old: 65536/65536, New 1073676288/65532)io[2813]: alsa-source.c: Resume failed, couldn't restore original fragment settings. (Old: 65536/65536, New 1073676288/65532)io[2813]: alsa-source.c: Resume failed, couldn't restore original fragment settings. (Old: 65536/65536, New 1073676288/65532)io[2813]: alsa-source.c: Resume failed, couldn't restore original fragment settings. (Old: 65536/65536, New 1073676288/65532)io[2813]: alsa-source.c: Resume failed, couldn't restore original fragment settings. (Old: 65536/65536, New 1073676288/65532)io[2813]: alsa-source.c: Resume failed, couldn't restore original fragment settings. (Old: 65536/65536, New 1073676288/65532)io[2813]: alsa-source.c: Resume failed, couldn't restore original fragment settings. (Old: 65536/65536, New 1073676288/65532)io[2813]: alsa-source.c: Resume failed, couldn't restore original fragment settings. (Old: 65536/65536, New 1073676288/65532)io[2813]: alsa-source.c: Resume failed, couldn't restore original fragment settings. (Old: 65536/65536, New 1073676288/65532)io[2813]: alsa-source.c: Resume failed, couldn't restore original fragment settings. (Old: 65536/65536, New 1073676288/65532)
Oct 30 18:14:34 apocalypse pulseaudio[2813]: alsa-source.c: Resume failed, couldn't restore original fragment settings. (Old: 65536/65536, New 1073676288/65532)
```

After a while the logs grow to large sizes and fill up all of my /var partition. In VirtualBox there is an option to choose between pulseaudio and alsa for sound, but it seems to have no effect. I am using virtualbox-3.0 packages, not the ose version. My system is up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First please take a look at [Anyone experiencing audio issues with VirtualBox on Linux and has a solution?](https://superuser.com/questions/7453/anyone-experiencing-audio-issues-with-virtualbox-on-linux-and-has-a-solution) for additional info.

As I note there, from 9.04->9.10 Ubuntu changed from ALSA to PulseAudio for the host sound support.

So you need to tell VirtualBox that your host audio is now PulseAudio - this seems for some reason to be a setting on EVERY virtual machine, so you'll need to change it on all of the ones you run.  Changing it on one and not on another is probably a very bad idea.

You'll most probably have to make the change with no VM's running.  Then stop and restart virtualbox.  Hopefully at that point the messages to /var/log/ will cease.

Failing that, if audio works fine from the VMs and you're still seeing the messages, you might want to take a look at logrotate to manage the logfiles:  http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html

Hope this helps!  If so please give the answer a thumbs-up.  Thanks!
-pbr

Comment: Also... sorry it took so long to reply to this!  I've been primarily looking at questions tagged "linux" - and this one's not tagged "linux".  Now that I know there's a "karmic" tag I'll take a look at the rest of them as well.